# Where to place meta tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a website which is developed using ASP and C#. Currently the meta tags are on the `master page`. The website works without any issue. When the users view the website the first page that loads is a `.html` and after that they're all `.aspx`. As far as I'm aware `html` pages can't be organised using a `master page`.

Now my question is do I leave the meta tags in the `master page` or shall I place them in the `html` page which gets loaded only at the start?

Below are the tags I currently have

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="keywords" content="some conten" />
<meta name="description" content="some description" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tags need to be on any page that needs them. They don't carry over from page to page, so they have to be on each page you want them applied to.

Therefore, it's not enough to simply have the meta tags on the .html page if you also want them to apply to the Web Forms pages.

Your keywords and description will likely want to change from page to page for [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) purposes. So you might want to define some basic stuff in your master page, but use a [ContentPlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow you to easily override the keywords and description from any child page.

Answer (score 0):

The master page defines the overall layout of your ASP.NET application. So each and every code in your master page would also be present inside the child pages. You have full control over child page inside your master page.

If you want to apply a meta tag, only to a specific page, then yes! Add the tag to the page and not the master page. However if there is a meta tag that needs to be applied over the website, then don't send it to a single page only. You can always copy/paste your meta tags to the place (page) that needs them or you want to apply them.

Master page will still work fine without any meta tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx (Meta tag)

Comment: Thanks for that it makes sense. However I should have mentioned before I added the html if I searched for the website in google it would be bring up the right description etc however now that the html page loads before everything else it doesn't bring up description and so on would you know if this is because the description meta tag is not on the html page?

Comment: Yes, if the master page is not connected to the HTML page, then the meta tag inside the master page would never be loaded inside the HTML page and you will have to write them into the HTML page yourself.